# getting multiple issues while creating a scrip to update hostnames in /etc/hosts file?

Tags: bash, script, shell-script, bash-scripting, localhost

I'm completely new to the scripts and hence need help to fix this.

We've around 3000 VMs & 450 Physical servers which are Linux based servers (few of then ubuntu starting from 9.x & few of them are Susu starting 8.X & majority of them are RHEL starting from 4.x till 7.4) on all of them I need to add few hostname entries with IP details into their respective /etc/hosts files.

I've different users on each server with full sudoers access which I can use
Hence I've created a CSV file with hostname, username & password format. which contains required details to log in. Filename is "hostname_logins.csv"

I need to upload a file (i.e. hostname_list to each of these servers and then update those same details in each of the servers host files.

I'll be running this script using one RHEL 6 server. (All of the other hosts are resolvable from this server & are reachable, I've confirmed it already.)

hence need help to fix this script.

script not sure what's wrong in it as I'm a new to scripts:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read hostname_login user_name user_password
do
        scp -p ./hostname_list $user_name:$user_password@$hostname_login:/tmp
        ssh -eS $user_name:$user_password@$hostname_login [bash -c "echo rishee | sudo -S mv /tmp/hostname_list ./hostname_list && cp -p /etc/hosts /etc/hosts.bkp && cat ./hostname_list >> /etc/hosts && rm -f ./hostname_list"]
done < hostname_logins.csv
```

I need to make this as a single script which will work on all these servers. thanks in advance.

Comment: for security sake you might want to disable using passwords and instead require SSH public/private keys

Comment: @ScottStensland I absolutely understand you but this customer is not ready to move over key based authentication. Hence there is nothing much I can do about it. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its always a good idea to make your scripts able to get executed repeatedly without side effects (idempotent) ... in above you are making a backup of the critical file  /etc/hosts however you are wiping over that same backup on next run - very dangerous if not lethal when /etc/hosts gets corrupted

run a preliminary script to simply copy /etc/hosts over to some working file then run your script against that working copy then once it works OK against some toy server then issue your script using actual /etc/hosts

Your above set of commands co-mingles using your userid and sudo which will give you permission errors ... I suggest you scp below file onto each box then execute it as sudo on each remote box ... understand the syntax inside /etc/hosts and confirm your appended lines conform to good syntax

```
#!/bin/bash

set -o errexit #  exit on any error
set -o xtrace  #  print command prior to execution

hostname_file=/root/hostname_list

working_hosts=/etc/hosts.working

mv /tmp/hostname_list  $hostname_file 

cp -p /etc/hosts $working_hosts

cat $hostname_file  >> $working_hosts

rm $hostname_file

echo here is contents of file $working_hosts

cat $working_hosts
```

above is not the finished script but it will take you 90% along ... on a toy server once you alter above to use real /etc/hosts file make sure you reboot that toy server and it checks out OK

Comment: What is toy server???